# Error in read.dcf(...) :Line starting '--- ... is malformed

Tags: r, shiny, knitr

I am getting an error at the time of publishing a Shiny app in R.

When i run the code locally, everything works. But at the time of publishing to shiny, i am getting the following error:

```
Error in read.dcf(...) : :Line starting '--- ... is malformed!
Calls: <Anonymous> -> rstudioEncoding -> readDcf -> read.dcf
```

How can this be fixed? Is this related to the header of the file?

The lines i have at the beginning are:

```
---
title: "Mapa de Corresponsales Bancarios Bancolombia"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```

Comment: .dcf files expect something : something, or something : ' ' # this is whitespace, but they will all have x : ' ', and your --- are missing `: ' ',` and those need to be adjusted, edited. cat(your_data), should show if you have a valid .dcf or not. for additional insights, ?read.dcf for .dcf valid file rules. I understand the visual appeal of `---` as record separators, but .dcf does not.

Comment: @Chris can you explain your answer with an example, please?

Comment: Just looking above, you see `---` (new-line \n), then `title: 'Mapa...`. The first line `---` is not valid .dcf because it doesn't have `:` and a space after the `:`. `title: 'Mapa...`, and the other record lines are valid because they do have 'something: something', then they arrive at another invalid `---`, that doesn't have `:` after it. if you `dput(head(my_data)) `and copy the `structure(...)` output here as Data, perhaps we can help resolve. I don't know why, but when you run your 'shiny' outside your local env, it extects a .dcf type file and your's is not, yet.

Comment: So it is earlier in your publishing chain that you need to address the format of the file you want to publish. Perhaps your share the steps you went through before, plus some dput(data), and better shiny experts than me will weigh in.

Comment: The entire code which works locally is uploaded at https://docs.google.com/document/d/14lNYdBsenytO2XxTabiO0fbFmKD9gNhm93UpKgew0tY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The beauty of `dput` is that it provides, generally, sufficient data to assess a problem. Now, imagine I work in a very old computer with quite limited hard drive space, negligible ram...so, you politely provide 'just enough data as needed' rather than 'all the data there is', via `dput`, and I don't risk overloading my very old computer that my wife keeps threatening to upgrade. You would then, put the working code, and a dput of data above and have a good question the people would presumably upvote.

Comment: The output of the file is:
structure(c("function (x, df1, df2, ncp, log = FALSE) ", "{", 
"    if (missing(ncp)) ", "        .Call(C_df, x, df1, df2, log)", 
"    else .Call(C_dnf, x, df1, df2, ncp, log)", "}"), dim = c(6L, 
1L), dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ""), class = "noquote")

Comment: And each and every one of those `x, df1, df2, ncp, log`, has data...Alright, `debug('whatever_your_function_is_named'), walk through and figure out which data is supposed to be .dcf, if they're not all supposed to be, and restate your question.

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens when there is a problem in the package description file. Usually you can spot the package name with problem but as in your case it is '...' which is generic.
To resolve this you need to follow a series of steps:

1. Get the location of your installed pacakges using `.libPaths()`
2. Use the following script to identify the faults

```
library(tools)

# I am creating two vectors for each successful and failed description files
successful_files <- c()
error_vector <- c()

# Specify the directory you have received from .libPaths()
dir_path <- "your-package-directory"

# Get the list of DESCRIPTION files in all subfolders
desc_files <-
  list.files(
    path = dir_path,
    pattern = "DESCRIPTION",
    recursive = TRUE,
    full.names = TRUE
  )

# Loop through the files
for (file in desc_files) {
  tryCatch({
    # Attempting to read the file
    desc <- read.dcf(file)
    
    # If successful, add to successful_files vector and show a console message
    successful_files <- c(successful_files, file)
    cli::cli_alert_success(paste0("Successfully loaded ", file))
  }, error = function(e) {
    # If an error occurs, add to error_vector and show a console message
    error_vector <- c(error_vector, file)
    cli::cli_alert_danger(paste0("Failed to loaded ", file))
  })
}

# Print error vector or follow console for errors
print(paste("Files with errors: ", error_vector))
```

3. Manually check the DESCRIPTION file in the error locations and see
   for any problem (you can compare it with the correct ones)
4. After you have modified the file, try using `read.dcf()` at the same file to see if it works correctly
5. Continue with your process which caused this error and it should work fine.

Keep Coding!